# In Android Screen Recording - How can I get each frame?

Tags: android, javacv, mediarecorder, android-ffmpeg

I am using the MediaRecorder and MediaProjection Api for recording the screen in android app. I am not able to get each frame that I can send over a rtmp stream. For publishing over an RTMP stream I am using JAVACV Android library.

For eg - In case of live streaming through camera, we can get each frame in onPreviewFrame() callback. After getting each frame I simply use the FFmpegFrameRecorder of JAVACV library for streaming each frame on to the rtmp url.

How can I achieve the same with screen recording?

Any help would be appreciated here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried get the key frame buffer from `muxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, info)` assuming you are doing something similar to: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ScreenRecordActivity.java (assuming frame shows up frequently enough which it may not for your purposes).

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Yes I have tried this but it doesn't satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly there is no callback interface with MediaProjection which can give you buffer of screen captured frame, But it is quite possible with [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture). Here is one implementation [ScreenCapturerAndroid](https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc/blob/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/ScreenCapturerAndroid.java) of screen capturing with SurfaceTexture.

> An implementation of VideoCapturer to capture the screen content as a video stream.
>    Capturing is done by  MediaProjection on a  SurfaceTexture. We interact with this
>     SurfaceTexture using a  SurfaceTextureHelper.
>    The SurfaceTextureHelper is created by the native code and passed to this capturer in
>    VideoCapturer.initialize(). On receiving a new frame, this capturer passes it
>   as a texture to the native code via  CapturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(). This takes
>    place on the HandlerThread of the given SurfaceTextureHelper. When done with each frame,
>    the native code returns the buffer to the   SurfaceTextureHelper

But if you want to send stream of your app view then following screen capturer will help you.

```java
public class ScreenCapturer {
    private boolean capturing = false;
    private int fps=15;
    private int width,height;
    private Context context;
    private int[] frame;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private View contentView;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public ScreenCapturer(Context context, View view) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contentView = view;
    }

    public void startCapturing(){
        capturing = true;

        mHandler.postDelayed(newFrame, 1000 / fps);
    }
    public void stopCapturing(){
        capturing = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(newFrame);
    }
    private Runnable newFrame = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (capturing) {
                int width = contentView.getWidth();
                int height = contentView.getHeight();
                if (frame == null ||
                        ScreenCapturer. this.width != width ||
                        ScreenCapturer.this.height != height) {

                    ScreenCapturer.this.width = width;
                    ScreenCapturer.this.height = height;

                    if (bmp != null) {
                        bmp.recycle();
                        bmp = null;
                    }
                    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                            height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
                    frame = new int[width * height];
                }
                canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, width, height, null);
                canvas.translate(-contentView.getScrollX(), - contentView.getScrollY());
                contentView.draw(canvas);

                bmp.getPixels(frame, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);


               //frame[] is a rgb pixel array compress it to YUV if want and send over RTMP

                canvas.restore();
                mHandler.postDelayed(newFrame, 1000 / fps);

            }
        }
    };


}
```

**Usage**

```java
...
//Use this in your activity 

private View parentView;

parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentView);
capturer = new ScreenCapturer(this,parentView);

//To start capturing
 capturer.startCapturing();


//To Stop capturer
capturer.stopCapturing();
```

Using this you can send a view contents to RTMP stream, You may use parent view of your activity to capture all contents of an activity.